# How redirect nohup stdout to stdin

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a way to redirect the `nohup` output to the stdin instead of `nohup.out` ?

I've tried:

`nohup echo Hello > /dev/stdin 2>&1 &`

But it does not the trick.

Comment: `/dev/stdin` here is the standard input of the command itself. Whose standard input to you want to receive "Hello"?

Comment: Isn't the point of `nohup ... &` to disconnect the process from your terminal? Are you trying to get the process to read it's own output? I'd start with `man nohup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *nohup* command purposefully detaches itself from the stdin, so there is nothing it expects to read in itself, and thus I think what you are really after in this question, is redirecting the output of *nohup* as the stdin for the next command. (Well somebody has to read the stdin, and it ain't *nohup*.)

Further, POSIX mandates that the output goes to the *nohup.out* file in the working directory, if the file can be successfully opened. So what you can do is to wire the stdin of the following commands from the *nohup.out* file. For instance:

```
$ nohup echo Hello 2>/dev/null; read VAR 0<nohup.out; echo "VAR=$VAR"
VAR=Hello
```